# for loop mysteriously not running

Tags: javascript, arraylist

code:

```js
var m = [
  "█","█","█","█","█","█","█","█",
  "█","█","█","█","█","█","█","█",
  "█","█","█","█","█","█","█","█",
  "█","█","█","█","█","█","█","█",
  "█","█","█","█","█","█","█","█",
  "█","█","█","█","█","█","█","█",
  "█","█","█","█","█","█","█","█",
  "█","█","█","█","█","█","█","█"
];

for (var i = 0; i > m.length, i++;) {
  console.log(m[i]);
}
```

it seems like the for loop isn't running at all, because putting in any value in console.log does nothing.

what's wrong?

(also, doing `console.log(m)` by itself outputs U+2588 fine.)

Comment: What does `m` look like? Give us a sample of five or six elements.

Comment: Check your loop conditional. [MDN `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 1):

`i > m.length` should be `i < m.length` because you're attempting to iterate from 0 to the length of the array

The gist of it is that your iterator (i) should be initaliased as 0 (which it is), but you're checking if it's *greater* than the length of `m`, which is presumably greater than 0; so because you initialise i with a value of zero, then check if it's greater than the length of m, it'll always evaluate to false whether m has any members or not.

Comment: Sorry, did not work. Got nothing.

Comment: @silvxrcat That is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

`i` needs to be less than `m.length`, and you had a couple of syntax errors in your for statement.

```js
const m = ['a','b','c']

for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
  console.log(m[i]); // m is a list of U+2588s.
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Comment: @silvxrcat It’s the same answer as what you said didn’t work?